# Is there a way to Scrape Twitter with selenium depending on different keywords automatically?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am working on a project where I collect tweets depending on different 30 keywords, I used selenium since I need very old tweets, However, I have to enter each keyword manually each time, my question, is there a way that I can specify the required keywords from the beginning and it will search for it automatically? Like when I am using Tweepy I can simply specify the required keywords from the beginning and it will get all the tweets about it like :

```
keywords= ['cat','dog','Rabbit']

stream_tweet.filter(track=keywords,languages=['en'])
```

is there a way with selenium to do the same?

Comment: Why not? Are you facing any error/issue?

Comment: yes  I do the code I'm using now is:                                                                  searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@aria-label="Search query"]')
keyword = input('what is the keyword: ')
searchbox.send_keys(keyword) ,which get one keyword on the search bar,when I made a list it gave me the problem : Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Latest"}
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.88)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the list items one by one as follows:

```
keywords= ['cat','dog','Rabbit']
for keyword in keywords:
    stream_tweet.filter(track=keyword,languages=['en'])
```

Comment: This works great with Twitter API,but how do I apply it on selenium ? when I automate the search bar and made the keyword list,I tried using the same loop but it still give me the message "  Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document "

Comment: Sounds to be different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: ok ,will do ,thank you